# How do I change the title of the tabs in Appixia apps?

Tags: mobile, e-commerce, appixia

I'm using the dashboard to build a simple app, and trying to figure out how I can control the titles that appear on the tab bar.

Comment: I selected the first item that appears in the app-tabs list (top left part of dashboard) then edited the title field. However this only changes the title of the tab (the upper title i mean) and not the tab label appearing right below the little icon !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok got it. To change the tab-icon title, I needed to choose the Root module and then edit the Tabs fields then edit the specific tab that needs updating.

Works smoothly.